# Please complete required fields message box

Tags: vb.net, messagebox

I'm trying to do a "`Please complete required fields`" messagebox. 
Tt does show up but `"Account Created"` also pops out just right after "`Please complete required fields`" appears whenever I try entering even one character in a textbox or clicking one of the two radio button. 
Also instead of "`Please complete required fields`", "`User already exists!`" shows up whenever the fields are empty.

Can somebody tell me what's wrong with my codes?

Thank you....

```
Public Class CreateAccount

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

            Try
                Using conn = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection()
                    conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                                            "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Thesis\Thesis\Database2.accdb"


                    Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO tbl_user (username, [password],facultymember,student) " & _
                                        "VALUES (@uname, @pwd,@fmem,@stud)"
                    Dim sqlCom As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, conn)
                    sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", TextBox1.Text)
                    sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pwd", TextBox2.Text)
                    sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fmem", RadioButton1.Checked)
                    sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stud", RadioButton2.Checked)

                    conn.Open()

                    Dim strUsername As String = TextBox1.Text
                    Dim boolUsernameExists As Boolean = False

                    Using dbConnection As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Thesis\Thesis\Database2.accdb")
                        dbConnection.Open()
                        Using dbCommand As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("select count(username) from tbl_user where username like ?", dbConnection)
                            dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", strUsername)
                            Dim result As Integer = DirectCast(dbCommand.ExecuteScalar(), Integer)
                            If result > 0 Then
                                boolUsernameExists = True
                            End If
                        End Using
                        dbConnection.Close()
                    End Using

                    If boolUsernameExists Then
                        MessageBox.Show("Username already exists!")
                        Return
                End If
                Dim sqlRead As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader = sqlCom.ExecuteReader()

                conn.Close()

                If TextBox1.Text = "" Or TextBox2.Text = "" Or RadioButton1.Checked = False Or RadioButton2.Checked = False Then
                    MessageBox.Show("Please complete the required fields.", "Authentication Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                End If

                RadioButton1.Checked = False
                RadioButton2.Checked = False

                TextBox1.Text = ""
                TextBox2.Text = ""

                MessageBox.Show("Account created successfully!")

                Me.Hide()
                LoginUser.Show()


            End Using

            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show("Error:" & ex.Message)
            End Try

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Me.Hide()
        LoginUser.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

    End Sub


    Private Sub Textbox2_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox2.KeyPress

        Dim KeyAscii As Short = Asc(e.KeyChar)
        Select Case KeyAscii
            Case System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Back  '<--- this is for  backspace
            Case 13
                e.Handled = True
                SendKeys.Send("{TAB}")   '<---- use to tab to next textbox or control
                KeyAscii = 0
            Case Is <= 32
                ' KeyAscii = 0
            Case 48 To 57     '<--- this is for numbers 
                Exit Sub
            Case 65 To 90     '<--- this is for Uppercase Alpha 
                Exit Sub
            Case 97 To 122     '<--- this is for Lowercase Alpha 
                Exit Sub
            Case Else
                e.Handled = True
                MessageBox.Show("You can only input letters and numbers!", "Create Account")
        End Select
    End Sub

    Private Sub RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles RadioButton1.CheckedChanged

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Nothing in the TextBox1_TextChanged Sub? Why are you first call the SQL Command and after that check for empty textboxes?

Comment: Can you please explain further especially on the SQL Command part? Thanks @DavidSdot

Comment: You call "INSERT INTO tbl_user..." using TextBox1.Text and AFTER that you check if it is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with DavidSdot, your code is out of order.

Here is an example that might work. I say might because im not very good at vb.net. So you might need to change a few things to make it work. However, that being said, the following might do you well regarding the correct order in which it should go.

```
Try
        Using conn = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection()
            conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                                    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Thesis\Thesis\Database2.accdb"

            If ((TextBox1.Text <> "" And TextBox2.Text <> "") And (RadioButton1.Checked <> False Or RadioButton2.Checked <> False)) Then
                conn.Open()
                Using dbCommand As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("select count(username) from tbl_user where username like ?", conn)
                    dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", TextBox1.Text)
                    Dim result As Integer = DirectCast(dbCommand.ExecuteScalar(), Integer)
                    If result = 0 Then
                        Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO tbl_user (username, [password],facultymember,student) " & _
                                "VALUES (@uname,@pwd,@fmem,@stud)"
                        Dim sqlCom As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, conn)
                        sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", TextBox1.Text)
                        sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pwd", TextBox2.Text)
                        sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fmem", RadioButton1.Checked)
                        sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stud", RadioButton2.Checked)

                        Dim sqlRead As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader = sqlCom.ExecuteReader()

                        RadioButton1.Checked = False
                        RadioButton2.Checked = False

                        TextBox1.Text = ""
                        TextBox2.Text = ""

                        MessageBox.Show("Account created successfully!")

                        Me.Hide()
                        LoginUser.Show()
                    Else
                        MessageBox.Show("Username already exists!")
                        Return
                    End If
                End Using
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Please complete the required fields.", "Authentication Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            End If

            conn.Close()
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error:" & ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, It actually did work for me! I'll make good use of this and also study it to avoid encountering problems like what I've posted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should really take a look at the logic of Button1_click sub, because it is really hard to understand.

- You opening your database twice
- you already inserted a user with username="" and password="" thats why you get user exists message when you have not enter anything
- *Account created successfully!* is always shown after *Please complete the required fields* as there is no check/return/whatever when fields as missing

No idea why the DB Insert is called on every keystroke as there is no code for that in what you posted

Comment: Sorry if it's all confusing, even I am confuse in what I'm doing as I'm only a beginner. Do I have to take off the 2nd code where I opened the database? I also don't get the part with username and password, also what do I put to fix Account created successfully. Thank you so much for the answer btw! @DavidSdot